# Adding XYZ tiles to images with layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, xyz-tiles

I have made a python script that loads several KML files and I'm gonna render them with a QPainter on a QImage. I set the extent to the QgsMapSettings.fullExtent(), when all my layers are part of the QgsMapSettings and added via `QgsMapSettings.setLayers(layers)`. I only extent the scale of the view by 1.1 or 1.2 to just have a better view of the data with

```
rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
ms.setExtent(rect)
```

This works all great and I gonna save the image with the QImage.save function. The only problem I have is, that I have a XYZ Tiles layer, based on OpenStreetMap and I'm not able to add it to my Image.

I tried picking the layer with `QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("OpenStreetMap")`and adding it to my layers list and finally add it to QgsMapSettings with the `QgsMapSettings.setLayers(layers)` method, but all that happens is that it shows the geo-coordinates as points of the KML files, but not the XYZ layer.

When I try to add the layer after my KML layers, just with `QgsMapSettings.setLayers(osm_layer)`, then my image only shows the lowest zoom level, without any data on it, which makes sense, because all the layers, which I have added before, are gone.

So what exactly I'm doing wrong?